# How to properly clean up open menu when navigating to next page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, use-effect

I have created simple but working dropdown-menu. In this example menu does not contain anything but text 'menu' and have no styles.

When "open menu"-button is clicked, app shows `div` that contains the menu, and adds eventListener to document click events. When eventListener is added and user click anywhere in document, function checks if click was happened inside the menu, and if so, does nothing. If click was outside the menu, it removes eventHandler and closes the menu.

Is there something wrong with this aproach? The major problem with this is that if menu is open when I click any link on page, I got this nasty react warning:

> index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

I have added `useEffect` cleanup function to remove eventHandler if menu is open, but that does not help, I still got same error message.

Can you point me what I have done wrong?

```
const DropDown = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const closeMenu = (event: MouseEvent) => {
    if (event.target && event.target instanceof HTMLElement && ref.current) {
      if (ref.current.contains(event.target)) return;
    }

    document.removeEventListener('click', closeMenu);
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const toggleMenu = () => {
    if (!open) {
      document.addEventListener('click', closeMenu);
      setOpen(true);
    } else {
      document.removeEventListener('click', closeMenu);
      setOpen(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (open) {
        document.removeEventListener('click', closeMenu);
        setOpen(false);
      }
    };
  }, [closeMenu]);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={toggleMenu}>open menu</button>
      {open && <div ref={ref}>menu</div>}
    </>
  );
};

export default DropDown;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is caused by the `setOpen(false);` in the `useEffect` hook: the clean-up function is called when the component unmounts therefore it make no sense setting its state. For the same reason, the check on whether the menu is open or not is redundant; if the menu is unmounted, you can remove the event handler regardless.

Try:

```js
const DropDown = () => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const ref = useRef < HTMLDivElement > (null);

    /*
     *"useCallback()" hook will avoid unnecessary re-creating
     * the function at each re-render
     */
    const closeMenu = useCallback((event: MouseEvent) => {
      if (event.target && event.target instanceof HTMLElement && ref.current) {
        if (ref.current.contains(event.target)) return;
      }

      /* 
       * You do not need to remove the event handler here
       * you create it when the component is mounted and
       * remove it when it is unmounted via the "useEffect()" hook
       */
      //document.removeEventListener('click', closeMenu);
      setOpen(false);
    }, []);

    const toggleMenu = () => {
      /*
       * This is not necessary, you can do it in one line.
       * Actually, you can entirely remove the function and
       * call 'setOpen(!open)' directly from the button:
       * <button onClick={() => {setOpen(!open)}}>
       */
      //if (!open) {
      //  document.addEventListener('click', closeMenu);
      //  setOpen(true);
      //} else {
      //  document.removeEventListener('click', closeMenu);
      //  setOpen(false);
      //}
      setOpen(!open);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      document.addEventListener('click', closeMenu);
      return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('click', closeMenu);
      };
    }, [closeMenu]);

    return ( <
      >
      <
      button onClick = {
        toggleMenu
      } > open menu < /button> {
        open && < div ref = {
            ref
          } > menu < /div>} <
          />
      );
    };

    export default DropDown;
```

Comment: This solution started to work when I added another ref to button-element, and in closeMenu-function I added a check if click was happening inside of button element. Otherwise the menu was closed before it was opened when clicking that button. Thank you!